# get relations table data is empty

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

i am using laravel 8.
i am try to get data with many to many relationship but give me empty data for related table

it's database

[image]

Order Model

```
 public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Product Model

```
    public function orders(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }
```

and fetch Query is

```
        $orders = Order::query()->with("products")->get();
```

Result

[image]

i am also check

```
        $orders = Order::query()->has("products")->get();
```

give me same result

Comment: Does `Order::first()->produts()->dd();` show the query you expect? Is there data in the `order_product` table?

Comment: yeah data is available in order_product table i also match the ids with both tables it's fine

Comment: Can you check the query log to make sure nothing weird is going on? `DB::enableQueryLog(); $orders = Order::query()->with("products")->get(); dd($orders->toArray(), DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: @IGP ```dd(DB::enableQueryLog());``` give me null and ```dd($orders->toArray());``` give me array:5 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▶]
  1 => array:6 [▶]
  2 => array:6 [▶]
  3 => array:6 [▶]
  4 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => "0000000017"
    "status" => 1
    "total" => "111"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "products" => []
  ]
]

Comment: @IGP ```Order::first()->produts()->dd();``` give me this result ```"select * from `products` inner join `order_product` on `products`.`id` = `order_product`.`product_id` where `order_product`.`order_id` = ?"
```

Comment: @IGP   ```$orders = Order::query()->has("products")->get();
        dd($orders[0]->products()->get());``` when i try this so show related products

Comment: Could you post examples of what is in the `orders`, `order_product` and `products` tables? Screenshots would be nice showing the table headings.

Comment: can you put screenshots of your models? also you need to read about a pivot in Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you are editing your query like this it will work

```
 $orders = Order::fist();
 $orders->products;
```

**Why?** becuse the pivot table.

what is the pivot table? Let me explain.

when you are working with `many-to-many` relations you must define an intermediate table like your table:`order_prodcts`.
so Laravel here provides some very helpful ways of interacting with this table.

So here’s a `database` structure:

```
orders:
   - id
   - title

products:
   - id
   - title

order_product:
   - id
   - title
```

The final table in the list: `order_product` is called a `pivot` table

**let's take your example**

let's assume our `Order` model has many `Product` models that it is related to. After accessing this relationship, we may access the intermediate table using the relation method you are defining on the models like:

**1-Your `Product` Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //some code

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**2-Your `Order` Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    //some code

    public function produtc()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Here each Product model we retrieve is automatically assigned a relation method. This relation method contains a model representing the intermediate `order_product` table.

**SO here try to get  you orders with your products**

```
public function index()
{

    $orders = Order::get();
    dd($orders->products); //Laravel will handel the pivot and will return your order products
}
```

**Now**, there are several things to mention when using pivot.

- Pivot table fields by default should be only two fields: foreign key to each of the tables `order_id` `product_id`
- Name of the pivot table should consist of `singular` names
- Names should be arranged in `alphabetical` order in your case `o` is first of `p` so your table will be called `order_product`

**Finally** Thank you for finishing the read I hope you gained any information from this answer

Comment: i found solution. it's empty because of eager loading. I disabled eager loadding so it's working fine... thanks for help